# Howdy does CPF417A message get received when opening query file?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am currently working on 3 programs. Program A is a CL which will override physical file ECIFCTP with SHARE(*YES) and call RPG program B to process it. After the processing program B will call program C, another CL to open query file on this physical file to filter out the records. When I actually ran the program the OPNQRYF statement in program C will cause error message CPF417A "Handling null capable fields is not valid for open of member ECIFCTP". Why did this happen? How to avoid it?

Comment: Just a side note:  OPNQRYF is an old technique that is no longer encouraged.  IBM is not including it in performance or functionality enhancements.  While it may be acceptable in some environments to have it remain in legacy programs, it would generally not be advised to create any new usage of it.   The newer SQE query optimizer does not support OPNQRYF.  You might consider OPNQRYF essentially deprecated in favor of SQL.

Comment: If you ever decide to go that route, IBM has a paper on [Converting from OPNQRYF to SQL](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/partnerworld/pub/whitepaper/13d32.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sharing the open data path with `SHARE(*YES)`.  The open parameters must be the same in all of the programs that access the shared open data path.

In this case program B and program C do not have the same [ALWNULL](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzasd/sc092508358.htm) setting.

The setting in CL is on the [DCLF](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/cl/dclf.htm) statement.  For example: `DCLF ... ALWNULL(*YES)`

Comment: So, what is the solution? Do I need to change the F spec in program B?

Comment: @God_of_Thunder The ALWNULL setting is on the `H` spec.  It must be the same between programs B and C.

Comment: Any other changes to program A and C?

Comment: No changes to A.  B and C must have the same ALWNULL and open options (input, update, delete).  And of course you must handle the possible NULL values accordingly.

Comment: Program C is a CL. How to add ALWNULL in a CL?

Comment: Because of various other reasons I did not implement OPNQRYF in the end. But still, thanks.